# Passing C parameters to a dll from Vb.net 2010

Tags: c, vb.net

Im trying to call a C++ dll from Vb.net.The function which Iam calling is declared in the dll as given below

`extern "C" DWORD PASCAL EXPORT STDFUPRT_CreateMappingFromDevice(PCHAR szDevLink, PMAPPING *ppMapping, PDWORD pNbAlternates)`

where pchar is a pointer to an array of bytes(string)
pdword is a pointer to a word

Pmapping is a structure as given below

```
**typedef struct {

DWORD       dwStartAddress;
DWORD       dwAliasedAddress;
DWORD       dwSectorIndex;
DWORD       dwSectorSize;
BYTE        bSectorType;
BOOL        UseForOperation;
} MAPPINGSECTOR, *PMAPPINGSECTOR;

typedef struct {

BYTE            nAlternate;
char            Name[MAX_PATH];
DWORD           NbSectors;
PMAPPINGSECTOR  pSectors;   
} MAPPING, *PMAPPING;**
```

I have tried sending sequential 283 bytes since thats the total structre size but it wont work.Ive tried marshalling as given bellow but it work as well.

```
Structure PMAPPING
    Dim nAlternate As Byte

    Dim name As IntPtr
    Dim nbsector As Int32
    Dim psector As IntPtr

End Structure
    Dim m_pMapping As PMAPPING
    m_pMapping.name = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(259)
    m_pMapping.psector = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(17)

    Dim tmpbuffer() As Byte
    'load symbolic link
    tmpbuffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(devpathstr)

    'Context.szdevlink = devpathstr
    dwRet = STDFUPRT_CreateMappingFromDevice(tmpbuffer, m_pMapping, alt2)
    'check return string value        
    Dim teststr As String
    teststr = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(m_pMapping.name)
    'teststr returns garbage value
```

Thanks looking forward for your suggestion

Comment: All of the structure sizes you mentioned are wrong.  Talk to the C programmer who wrote it.

Comment: The code working in Visual stdio c++.net hence Iam only using thier Dlls.Calls to dlls are working fine in terms of functionality in C++ example.I have the example too you can download it from 4shared.com/file/Slatu3wQ/Software.html I have uploaded it here .Its the project called DFUdemo and the code is in Dialog.cpp.